# Multiple vertices after editing giving wrong start and end x, y co-ordinates

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, editing, vertices

Initially I generated some polylines across the river at various locations. I found some of them are smaller in size and not fitting the river width, Therefore, I edited those using advanced editing tool by using extend polyline tool. However,I did not have knowledge that extending would create one more vertex in the middle.

When I am computing distance using my script, the script is calculating distance between two earlier vertices it did not consider the another end vertices to compute the x,y of the actual end point of the modified lines.

How can I solve this?

I tried to delete middle vertices still I find wrong distance. I think that I may need to rebuild/repair the geometry, but I am not sure.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you post a portion of your script so we can see how you are calculating your distance?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for your error could be the fact that your edit is not saved when you compute the full length. Otherwise you should have the new length and the new "end" from your script.

If this is not the case and you want to get rid of your extra vertices (because your script is based on a count of the vertices, for instance), you can use simplify your lines with "point remove" and a very small tolerance.